# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in nodejs with mangoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose

my mongoose db is connecting with nodes server.but when I am inserting the values. its getting the error is

```
E:\S-chat\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:246
        throw message;
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at processResults (E:\S-chat\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1581:31)
    at E:\S-chat\server\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1619:20
```

.Any solution please

Comment: Could it be the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353374/node-not-connecting-to-mongo-more-than-once)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the perfect solution is compatibility between mongoose and mango db server is

```
MongoDB Server 2.4.x: mongoose ~3.8, 4.x
MongoDB Server 2.6.x: mongoose ~3.8.8, 4.x
MongoDB Server 3.0.x: mongoose ~3.8.22, 4.x
MongoDB Server 3.2.x: mongoose >=4.3.0
```

npm install --save --save-exact mongoose@4.1.9

1. MongoDB version --MongoDB-3.2.4